# How can I create a Flutter widget that detects size changes, similar to how a RenderFlex overflowed error is detected?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to compare the size of the parent and child of the widget to perform certain actions when specific conditions are met, similar to how Flutter detects overflow in a RenderFlex and displays an error indicating how many pixels it exceeds the available size.

If you reduce the size of the window in a web browser and then initialize this code, you will encounter a render overflow error. I would like to modify the widget when there isn't enough space available.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool changeWidget = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Example'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return changeWidget
                ? const Text('Widget changed')
                : MeasureSize(
                    onChange: (size) {
                      print('childs width: ${size?.width} parents width: ${constraints.maxWidth}');
                      if (size!.width < constraints.maxWidth) {
                        setState(() {
                          changeWidget = true;
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          changeWidget = false;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                        Text('Example of text'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef OnWidgetSizeChange = void Function(Size? size);

class MeasureSizeRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  Size? oldSize;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  MeasureSizeRenderObject(this.onChange);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    Size? newSize = child?.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      onChange(newSize);
    });
  }
}

class MeasureSize extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasureSize({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChange,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return MeasureSizeRenderObject(onChange);
  }
}
```

Comment: check `CustomMultiChildLayout` - the docs say: "A widget that uses a delegate to size and position multiple children.

The delegate can determine the layout constraints for each child and can decide where to position each child. The delegate can also determine the size of the parent, but the size of the parent cannot depend on the sizes of the children."

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RenderProxyBox` like in your question and the Flutter notification system:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAnFbFoGM50

First, create a class to represent your notification.

```
/// Extends from Notification.
class SizeReporterNotification extends Notification {
  const SizeReporterNotification(this.size);

  /// Notification data.
  final Size size;
}
```

A `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` will allow us to wrap some widget in order to create notifications when its size changes.

Source:

```
/// A widget that reports its child's size to the notification system.
class SizeReporter extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const SizeReporter({super.key, required super.child});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderSizeReporter(context: context);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
    BuildContext context,
    RenderSizeReporter renderObject,
  ) {
    /// Update any additional properties added later.
  }
}
```

Since parent widgets can have access to their child's size during the layout phase, let's make a render object that:

- Wraps the widget whose size changes we want to be notified about.
- Holds a copy of that child's last size (obtained in the layout pass).

We can then compares the child's last size to the size of the child reported during a new layout pass. When the size of the child has changed (i.e. `_oldSize != newSize`), then we send out a `SizeReporterNotification`.

Source:

```
/// The render object that reports its size to the notification system.
class RenderSizeReporter extends RenderProxyBox {
  RenderSizeReporter({
    required BuildContext context,
    RenderBox? child,
  })  : _context = context,
        super(child);
 
  /// Required to access the [BuildContext] to dispatch the notification.
  final BuildContext _context;

  /// The previous size of the child.
  Size? _oldSize;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    /// Takes care of laying out the child and making sure its size is usable.
    super.performLayout();

    final newSize = child!.size;

    /// Only dispatch the notification if the size has changed.
    if (_oldSize != newSize) {
      _oldSize = newSize;
      SizeReporterNotification(newSize).dispatch(_context);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key, this.first = 200.0, this.second = 320.0});

  final double first;
  final double second;

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  late double _size = widget.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// The [NotificationListener] widget will listen for notifications that
    /// match the type specified in the generic type parameter, in this case
    /// [SizeReporterNotification].
    return NotificationListener<SizeReporterNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        log("size: ${notification.size}");

        /// Do something with the size.

        /// Tell the notification system that this notification has
        /// been handled; prevents this notification from bubbling up
        /// the widget tree any further.
        return true;
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(
            () => _size = _size == widget.first ? widget.second : widget.first,
          );
        },
        child: SizeReporter(
          child: AnimatedSize(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            child: Container(width: _size, height: _size, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In my question, I give an example of a row with texts. In this case, using the system that you tell me about, both the width of the row and the width of the screen coincide, but I am still unable to anticipate the overflow that happens to the texts. It would be a good idea if I could access the actual width of the texts, I know there is a way, using ```TextPainter``` but it requires you to pass the text to it, and then I would have to have a separate method where I send all the texts I'm going to put in my Row, and it is not what I am looking for, I am looking for a more scalable solution

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy), which jumps into the middle of the layout cycle and can make detailed decisions about placement and content, based on dry layouts of desired children.  It's possibly overkill, but it does expose the layout protocol that any fancy layout system uses in a relatively efficient way.  Be sure to check out the detailed well-written [user guide](https://boxy.wiki/) as well.